# Appending individual items to lists in pandas Series

Tags: python, list, pandas, append, series

I am creating a Multiindexed pandas Series and each item is a list. First, an empty list, then I append each of these lists individually. However, when I tried to do that in a naive manner, I've faced a problem. It is easily duplicated in this simple example:

```
blah = pd.Series([[]]*8)
blah[0].append(30)
blah
```

What I wanted to get is this:

```
0    [30]
1    []
2    []
3    []
4    []
5    []
6    []
7    []
```

Instead the output is this:

```
0    [30]
1    [30]
2    [30]
3    [30]
4    [30]
5    [30]
6    [30]
7    [30]
```

Instead of appending one of the lists, it appends all of them with the same value.

My question: is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way of doing this?

(Please keep in mind that I am actually working with Multiindex Series, though I think it doesn't matter for this particular problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use something like `[ [] for x in range(0,8) ]`

This will create a new list (`[]`) 8 times instead of referencing 8 times the same list.

Comment: Referencing... You get it wrong or you get it wrong.

Thank you, it works!

Answer (score 1):

You could also find dictionaries useful.

```
lists = {}
for i in range(8):
    lists[i] = []

lists[0] = [30]
```

returns

```
{0: [30], 1: [], 2: [], 3: [], 4: [], 5: [], 6: [], 7: []}
```

Answer (score -1):

What if you append None instead.

```
foo = [None]*30
foo[0] = 30
```

Comment: This does not answer the questions : it gives a different result.

Comment: @Bruce A wrong answer is still an answer. Downvote and move on IMO.

Comment: I believe it is clearer with None. You explicitly say that there is nothing there.